# Writing Corollaries into Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm taking Discrete Math and one of my homework problems from Epp's *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* asks me to prove the following:

> If $r$ and $s$ are any two rational numbers, then $\frac{r+s}{2}$ is rational.

It's pretty basic, and here is my proof:

> We will use the direct method. Let $r$ and $s$ be rational numbers such that \begin{align}r=\frac{a}{b},\:s=\frac{c}{d},\:\:\:\text{s. th.}\:\:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{1}.\end{align} Therefore we have \begin{align}\frac{r+s}{2}=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}{2}=\frac{ad+cb}{2bd}\tag{2},\end{align}and since the product of two integers is an integer and the sum of two integers is also an integer, $(2)$ is therefore the quotient of two integers, which is by definition a rational number.$\:\:\blacksquare$

Okay, so no problem there. But the next question now asks me to write a *corollary* to the proof above:

> For any rational numbers $r$ and $s$, $2r+3s$ is rational.

I know it is easily proved, but how do I write a corollary to a proof? Do I simply write "corollary:" and then continue? What should be re-stated and what should I assume to be a given from the previous proof? Epp only briefly talks about corollaries on page 168.

Thank you for your time, and please know that I recognize it is not your job to do my homework and nor would I ever ask it of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, we have the following theorems given to us from the text.

Theorem 4.2.1: Every integer is a rational number.

Theorem 4.2.2: The sum of any two rational numbers in rational.

Theorem 15 (from exercise 15):  The product of any two rational numbers is rational.

Now, question 25 asks derive(prove) a corollary(a word that simply means new theorem that uses the theorems listed above) using previously proved theorems.

Finally, I will establish how such a proof should look and why we call it a corally.

Proof:

If $s$ is rational, then $2s$ is rational. This follows because Theorem 4.2.1 says that every integer is rational so 2 is rational,and Theorem 15 says that the product of any two rational numbers is rational, so $2s$ must be rational.

Furthermore, we know that $3$ is an integer, so by Theorem 4.2.1, 3 is rational. Also, by Theorem 15 we know that $3r$ is rational.

In conclusion, by Theorem 4.2.2, $3r+2s$ is rational.(End of Proof)

Now, if you look at this proof you notice that I have used many other theorems to prove this. Thus we call this specific result a corollary. However, I'm sure I don't have to say this, but just in case, corollaries are just as true as theorems, and we prove them in the same way we prove a theorem.

Let me know if you have any more questions. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent and well-planned answer to my question. This gives me a good idea of how to write out such a corollary referencing the prior. I will write my proof now and submit it in a few weeks (I'm a few weeks ahead in the homework). Thank you for your time! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked your question and I think I can help you. In fact, I am a discrete math grader for a class that used that text book. A corollary is just another word for a theorem. However, it is a theorem that mainly uses the results of the another, more general(some would argue more important) theorem. Thus, as a grader if you are proving a corollary. I would be looking mostly for where you explicitly used the theorem that you had just recently proved. That is, use the fact that

If $r$ and $s$ are any two rational numbers, then $\frac{r+s}{2}$ is rational.

to prove that

For any rational numbers $r$ and $s$, $2r+3s$ is rational.

If you are confused about any of this just ask me a question in the comments and I'll try to help some more.

Comment: I suppose I could use the definitions I've used in the previous proof to support my argument in the corollary? For instance, if the sum of these two rational numbers is thus rational and the product of these rational numbers by any other rational number (in this case, two different integers) is rational by definition, then $2r+3s$ is thus rational. Does this sound right?

Comment: Alright, I just looked at the text book, and found the exact problem you are talking about. I will add a new answer and give a more complete explanation and example using a problem  from the book. Just give me a few moments.

Comment: Thank you, although this really isn't necessary...